# Изменение статуса нового заказа перед записью в базу

Tags: woocommerce, order

WooCommerce Как программно изменить статус нового заказа перед записью его в базу. Доставка - самовывоз. Оплата при получении

Comment: Добавьте больше информации.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_change_status_function' );
function my_change_status_function( $order_id ){

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'on-hold' );

}
```